# rdpwrapper library unavailable for download github link no good

Tags: remote-desktop, github

Where can I download RDP Wrapper Library  Github identifies that it is not available
(This repository has been disabled.)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this type of question is unsupportable.  Where you find software is outside the scope of Super User.  Additionally, based on the search results, it appears the original repository has been disabled for while.  Since the public forks of the repository are what search engines are picking up.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe these others repositories can help you:

1. https://github.com/TuxBel/rdpwrap
2. https://github.com/asmtron/rdpwrap
3. https://github.com/fig2k4/rdpwrap
4. https://github.com/camilohe/rdpwrap

Answer (score 0):

It's been mirrored on gitlab (with a few nice updates it seems)
https://gitlab.com/rdpwrap/rdpwrap

Comment: gitlab has removed this too